# Php file working locally but not on hosting platform

Tags: php

I 've got a simple php file that works on phpmyadmin locally, but it returns a blank page on the hosting server 000webhost.
It is a simple search engine on a local database but I can't even see the submit button on the server.
I have already tried to move the php file in and out the public_html folder.
The project name is charleroifurniture and the php file begins with define("SITE_ADDR", "http://localhost/charleroifurniture");

Comment: _"Php file working locally on phpmyadmin but not on hosting platform"_ - PHPMyAdmin is just a web based management tool for managing MySQL/MariaDB databases. Your application doesn't have anything to do with PHPMyAdmin, it connects directly to the database.

Comment: If you get a blank white page, check your web servers error log for any error messages that can help shed some light over what the issue is. A blank page is common if the server errors out (for any number of reasons).

Comment: OK. The page displays "About:blank". Where can I see the server error? The hosting server is 000Webhost.com. Regards.